Get current mute status with ALSA C library
I need to read current mute state of soundcard using ALSA C library.
There is one example how to mute:
Linux ALSA/Sound-API Questions - How do you mute?
But what about reading current mute state? Of course, I can do it using shell script or using system function inside c code. But I'd like to use ALSA C library functions.

What have you tried so far? The linked question uses snd_mixer_selem_set_playback_switch_all to mute all channels. A search for that function name might lead you to snd_mixer_selem_get_playback_switch which looks like a good starting point for playing around.

The way to get the Mute status from the ALSA C library is very simple:
int muted;
snd_mixer_selem_get_playback_switch(elem, SND_MIXER_SCHN_FRONT_LEFT, &muted);

If muted == 1, the channel is muted.
